# How can I change the Windows 11 taskbar weather to Celsius _without_signing in to widgets

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, weather

I would like the taskbar weather widget to use Celsius instead of Fahrenheit.  However, I don't want to sign in just for this feature to work.

Is there a way to configure this somewhere in the system?

Going into Weather app and changing the setting there doesn't seem to affect the taskbar icon.

Maybe there is a way to do this in the registry?

Answer (score 1):

In my  Windows 11 PC (version 22H2), the widget becomes inactive when I sign out

[image: Weather widget signed-out state]

so it seems you DO need to sign in.

You can customize the widget to display Celcius instead of Farenheit:

[image: Customize Widget step 1]

[image: Customize Widget step 2]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Are you signed in when you do that?  My requirement was that I don't want to log in .. this is going to be a VM template, and I don't want to personalize the image.